# Cumulative calculation in Oracle

Tags: sql, select, oracle9i

I have below `Emp` table that contains three columns (`empno, ename, salary`).

```
empno  ename   salary 
---------------------
 101   Ram     2000
 102   Kumar   1000
 103   Mani    3000
```

I need below output by displaying `Cumulative_Salary` from above table.

```
Empno Ename  Cumulative_Salary
-------------------------------
101   Ram    2000
102   Kumar  3000
103   Mani   6000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `SUM OVER`.

```
select 
  empno, ename, salary,
  sum(salary) over(order by empno) as cumulative_salary
from emp
order by empno;
```

By applying `ORDER BY empno` in the `OVER` clause, we implicitly apply `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, but you can of course make this explicit, if you want to.

Docs: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sum-analytic-function

Answer (score 0):

```
    select 
      empno
     , ename
     , sum(salary) as cumulative_salary
    from emp
    group by
      empno, ename
    order by empno;
```